# Need help getting images to stick to navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make my images stick to the navbar at the top. When I make the tab smaller, the pictures have a noticeable gap. I want to get rid of this gap before I start aligning the pictures vertically for phone usage.
I have managed to make it responsive horizontally, but the gap is bugging me a lot. I could just add a black background to hide it, but I feel like that takes away from it.

When I'm gonna make it more responsive, I'm going to use media queries, I wonder if that could solve the issue, but I don't think it would.
Any ideas on how this could be solved?

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.navbox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vh;
    background-color: #271f30;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.navbox img {
    height: 10vh;
}
.home {
    width: auto;
    height: 75px;   
}
.bildspel { 
}
.arrowleft {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
.arrowright {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
.tre {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 99vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.tre img {
    width: calc(100vw / 3);
    aspect-ratio: 1/1.75;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tre img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.15)
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>The Witcher - Streaming on Netflix</title>
<link href="seessess.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbox">
        <div></div>
        <a href="index.html">
            <img class="home" src="witcherlogo.png" alt="Logo">
        </a>    
    <div></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tre">
        <img src="Crop2.png" onClick="location.href='index.html'">
        <img src="Crop1.png" onClick="location.href='index.html'">
        <img src="Crop3.png" onClick="location.href='index.html'">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gap happens because your `vh` calculations don't add up. You can fix it by removing `height: 90vh;` from `.tre` so it will always stick to the nav bar.

It also helps to put your three images in a div, so you can use flex more easily. (the images are always 100% of their flex div container)

I added a media query to put the images under each other on a small screen.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vh;
    background-color: #271f30;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbox img {
    height: 10vh;
}
.tre {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.tre div {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.tre img {
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:100%;
}
.tre img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.15)
}

@media (max-width:300px) {
   .tre {
     flex-direction:column;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbox">
    <div></div>
    <a href="index.html">
      <img class="home" src="https://cataas.com/cat" alt="Logo">
    </a>    
    <div></div>
</div>
    
<div class="tre">
      <div>
          <img src="https://cataas.com/cat">
      </div>
      <div>
          <img src="https://cataas.com/cat">
      </div>
      <div>
          <img src="https://cataas.com/cat">
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This solved most of my problems. Thank you so much!

Comment: Did some more poking in my code and everything is solved now. You're a hero. Thank you so much.

Comment: @EmilS glad it helped! feel free to mark the question as answered!